# Symfony Expiration Time Calculation

Tags: php, time, symfony1

InSymfony (Doctrine) I am trying to create a public function with the code below.  What I'm trying to do is when a user submits a form, it calculated the expiration date for the item.   Here is the code I have so far but I don't know how to calculate the current time. I have taken pieces of code from different examples I have found on the internet but it fails every time.

```
class Car extends BaseCar
{
    public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null)
    {

    if ($this->isNew() && ! $this->getEndtime()) 
        {
            $now = THIS IS WHAT I NEED HELP WITH
            $this->setEndtime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $now + 86400 * sfConfig::get('item_duration')));
        }
        return parent::save($conn);
    }

}
```

The `item_duration` is set in the `App.yml` file. So I can set it as a site wide variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current time with this.

```
$now = time();
```

Comment: Well, the 86400 (24 hours in seconds) is there so that it can calculate the current day and time, plus 86400 times number of days (which in this case I have set to 30 days).  It looks like the time() only returns the current time.   Is there one the returns the date and the time?

Comment: `time()` returns a unix timestamp which is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970. Using that in your code should have the desired effect.

Comment: new \DateTime() ... you can place anything you need into datetime() to get the date and time you want..

Comment: Perfect!!   That worked!   Thanks a million guys! It kept setting the expiration time the same as the current time, but I found it was because I needed to change the item_duration to app_item_duration so it pulled the right number.   Thanks again guys.   Worked like a charm.